# Java reflection vs Jess

Tags: java, reflection, jess

it seems to me that Jess is a way to change dynamically what we put inside a Java class, when I've face the java Reflection, surprisingly seems to me that have the same objective.

If this is true, when should I use one or other ?

Cheers,

Comment: I would say that the purpose of `Reflection` is to **discover** dynamically what the author put in the class and then apply this knowledge in implementing our logic.

Comment: Yes, but I can do everything with java without jess 
(if I'm not mistaken) this is the first question.

Why should I put another type of language in Java. At are the benefits ? 

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jess does include a traditional programming language with the ability to manipulate Java objects, But the main part of what Jess does is allow you to write *declarative rules.* This is a completely different programming paradigm. In a traditional *imperative* language you write code that tells the computer explicitly how to solve a problem. In a declarative language, on the other hand, you describe the problem, and the language itself figures out how to solve it. Because Jess itself is written in Java, it makes no sense to say that Jess is more or less powerful than Java itself: it's just a different approach to programming, and it makes solving certain classes of problems easier.